# Why doesn't Object.keys work with DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, object

If you open the devtool here on this page and type the followings you'll get:

```
let scripts = $$('script');
scripts[0].src    // => "http://something....."
typeof scripts[0] // => "object"
```

But if I do `Object.keys(scripts[0])`, I get:

```
Object.keys(scripts[0]); //=> []
```

Why? Isn't `HTMLScriptElement` an object? If it is not, then what is it? How to enumerate its properties?

Comment: There's an experimental `properties` property for HTMLElements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement), it "Inherits properties from its parent, `HTMLElement`."  `Object.keys` only returns an objects own, enumerable properties, so you probably would want to use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop _without_ an enumerable property check.

Comment: It is returning DOM nodes not objects.@AlexanderNied for...in is the only one you shouldnt use. forEach, for, and for..of all should work

Comment: @arieljuod `.properties` appears to be part of the (deprecated) [microdata API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Microdata_DOM_API) and has nothing to do with `Object.keys`

Comment: @GifCo `for..of` won't work as a DOM node is not iterable. Note that the OP isn't concerned about iterating a collection of DOM nodes but about enumerating the properties of a DOM node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Description)

This means two things:

1. You don't get the keys that were inherited:

```js
function foo() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;
  this.c = 3;
}

// you get `a`, `b` and `c` as they are defined on the instance
console.log(Object.keys(new foo()));


function bar() {
  this.b = 2;
  this.c = 3;
}

bar.prototype.a = 1;

// you don't get `a` as it is inherited from the prototype
console.log(Object.keys(new bar()));
```

2. And you don't get the keys that are not enumerable:

```js
function foo() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;
  this.c = 3;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'a', {enumerable: false});
}

console.log(Object.keys(new foo()))
```

---

You can however work around this:

```js
const s = document.querySelector('script');
console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(s)));
```